# Two functions within a function?

Tags: python, function

I'm really new to this so it might be an easy answer I just can't figure out.

For my Python assignment, I'm supposed to call two separate functions under a function which is all under another function. I'm able to do:

```
def firstfunction():
    def second():
        blah blah blah
        blah blah blah
        blah blah blah
    print(second())
```

But I can't add a third function inside under the second one, what are some possible suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't"? Do you get an error? Show us the code that isn't working, and any error traceback you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work for you?

```py
def first():
    print("first")
    def second():
        print("second")
        def third():
            print("third")
        third()
    second()
```

Keep in mind that you cannot access a function that was declared in a nested function. That is, you cannot access `third` from `first` because it was declared within `second`.